# Displaying an mutable string in an webView

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a **Mutable String** as an output of my program and I am in need of displaying them in `UIWebView`.

Are there any available methods in `WebView` to display **string or mutable Strings** ?

The code of MutableString:

```
// interface


@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableString *theString;


//the string

    NSMutableString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];

    NSLog(@"Description : %@" , string);

    [[segue destinationViewController] setTheString:string];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body>%@/</body></html>", yourMutableString];  
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: i need to display the "theString" in WebView , how do i do that ?

Comment: You will have to load it as I have answered above. Is it not working?